# Can someone please give an explanation to these different outputs

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, command, command-prompt

Please see the 2 sample codes:

```
@ECHO off

Set RegQry=HKLM\Hardware\Description\System\CentralProcessor\0

REG.exe Query %RegQry% > checkOS.txt

Find /i "x86" < CheckOS.txt > StringCheck.txt


If %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (
     Echo "This is 32 Bit Operating system"
   set ProgFileDir=%ProgramFiles%
) ELSE (

     Echo "This is 64 Bit Operating System"
      set ProgFileDir=%ProgramFiles(x86)%
)
del checkos.txt
del stringcheck.txt

echo ---------------
echo "%ProgFileDir%"
echo ----------------
pause
```

This is giving me a wrong output:

```
"This is 64 Bit Operating System"
---------------
"C:\Program Files (x86"  <==Notice how the closing brace is trimmed
----------------
Press any key to continue . . .
```

If i change the position of the statement `set ProgFileDir=%ProgramFiles(x86)%` outside the bracket:

```
@ECHO off

Set RegQry=HKLM\Hardware\Description\System\CentralProcessor\0

REG.exe Query %RegQry% > checkOS.txt

Find /i "x86" < CheckOS.txt > StringCheck.txt


If %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (
     Echo "This is 32 Bit Operating system"
   set ProgFileDir=%ProgramFiles%
) ELSE (

     Echo "This is 64 Bit Operating System"
)
del checkos.txt
del stringcheck.txt

      set ProgFileDir=%ProgramFiles(x86)%
echo ---------------
echo "%ProgFileDir%"
echo ----------------
pause
```

I get the correct result:

```
"This is 64 Bit Operating System"
---------------
"C:\Program Files (x86)" <== with the closing brace
----------------
Press any key to continue . . .
```

What am i doing wrong here? I am running this batch file on Windows 7 64 bit OS.

Comment: Besides your question, you can simplify the code by detecting the system variable without creating 2 temporary files. [http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-64bit.html](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-64bit.html)

Answer (score 2):

I think your .bat file was getting confused with the `(` above `del checkos.txt` Also read about prefix with a caret: `^`

```
@ECHO OFF
Set RegQry=HKLM\Hardware\Description\System\CentralProcessor\0

REG.exe Query %RegQry% > checkOS.txt

Find /i "x86" < CheckOS.txt > StringCheck.txt


If %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (
     Echo "This is 32 Bit Operating system"
     set ProgFileDir=%ProgramFiles% 

) ELSE (  
ECHO "This is 64 Bit Operating System"
)
set ProgFileDir= %ProgramFiles(x86)%

del checkos.txt
del stringcheck.txt

echo ---------------
echo "%ProgFileDir%"
echo ----------------
pause
```

Also read about the set command [HERE](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html)

Answer (score 2):

```dos
@ECHO off
Set RegQry=HKLM\Hardware\Description\System\CentralProcessor\0
REG.exe Query %RegQry% > checkOS.txt
Find /i "x86" < CheckOS.txt > StringCheck.txt

If %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (
     Echo "This is 32 Bit Operating system"
   set "ProgFileDir=%ProgramFiles%"
) ELSE (

     Echo "This is 64 Bit Operating System"
      set "ProgFileDir=%ProgramFiles(x86)%"
)
del checkos.txt
del stringcheck.txt

echo ---------------
echo "%ProgFileDir%"
echo ----------------
GOTO :EOF
```

Using the `set "var=string"` syntax removes the `"string"` from the parser's scope and also ensures that any trailing spaces on the line are **not** included in the value assigned.

Since the `)` in `programfiles(x86)` is now within rabbit's ears, it is oart of a string, effectively turning off its special meaning (closing the `else` clause.) Possibly a more conventional way using the original syntax is to escape the `)` with a caret thus: `^)` which turns off the special meaning of characters as far as the parser is concerned and returns them to being ordinary characters.

?? I'm not sure whether the variable `programfiles(x86)` is established for 32-bit OSs. If this is so,

```
set "progfiledir=%programfiles%"
if defined programfiles(x86) set "progfiledir=%programfiles(x86)%"
```

would appear to accomplish the same result...